# Doesn't show featured image panel in Product editor in woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I use Impreza theme in my site. I installed woocommerce. In product page, I can't see **feature image panel**. I added below code to **function.php**, but it doesn't work. How can I fix it?

```
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails', array( 'post', 'page', 'movie', 'product' ) );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I founded. This problem was created due to the installation of the َAdvanced customer filed plugin.So When I got off it, the problem was solved.